# Designer.cs is deleted on adding object in DBML

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

My original dbml file had objects which had data connection to other server/db. As my db is changed to different server and i want to update my spproc when i delete the spproc and drag the new one dbml.designer.cs is deleted. I am using VS 2008 SP1. I can't regenerate all my dbmls as they have lots of tables, sps etc.. Inserting the using inside the dbml namespace doesn't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same problem. Bizarrely, the solution is to move any using statements into the namespace brackets.

For example, I had this (with the using statement at the top like you would normally see):

```
using System.Configuration;
namespace BuildDashboard.Data
{
    partial class DashboardDBDataContext
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I had to change it to this (With the using statement inside the namespace):

```
namespace BuildDashboard.Data
{
    using System.Configuration;

    partial class DashboardDBDataContext
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Once I made this change, my designer file was no longer deleted.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Move the 'using' statements inside the namespace, then you can right click on the .dbml file and 'Run custom Tool' to regenerate the designer file.